# Merging hierarchy of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have two dictionaries, and what I'm trying to do is a bit odd. Basically, I want to merge them. That's simple enough. But they're hierarchies of of dictionaries, and I want to merge them in such a way that if an item in a dictionary is itself a dictionary and exists in both, I want to merge those dictionaries as well. If it's not a dictionary, I want the values from the second dictionary to overwrite the values from the first one. Something sort of like this:

```
a = {0: {0: "a"},
     1: [0, 1, 2]}

b = {0: {1: "b"},
     1: [3, 4, 5]}

Merge(a, b)

#output:
{0: {0: "a",
     1: "b"},
 1: [3, 4, 5]}
```

Does that make sense? Because the key "0" contained a dictionary in both a and b, it merged those dictionaries as well. But in the case of the second key, it was a list so it just overwrote it.

So I suppose I'll be looking at some kind of recursive function? Not quite sure how to approach this one.

Thanks!

Edit: I forgot to mention one pretty crucial detail:

I need a function that works in both 2.6.2 and 2.7.3.

Comment: What if value of `1` is a list in one dict and `2` is a dict in the another dict?

Comment: Typically I don't think that will actually happen, but in such a case, I guess overwrite with the values from the other dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you might have nested dictionaries (based on your thinking in terms of recursion), something like this should work,

```
from copy import deepcopy

def merge(a, b):
    if isinstance(b, dict) and isinstance(a, dict):
        a_and_b = a.viewkeys() & b.viewkeys()
        every_key = a.viewkeys() | b.viewkeys()
        return {k: merge(a[k], b[k]) if k in a_and_b else 
                   deepcopy(a[k] if k in a else b[k]) for k in every_key}
    return deepcopy(b)
```

The return value of `merge(a, b)` is conceptually like creating a (deep) copy of `a` and running a recursive version of `a.update(b)`.

---

Using some nested examples,

```
a = {0: {0: 'a'},
     1: [0, 1, 2],
     2: [9, 9],
     3: {'a': {1: 1, 2: 2}, 'b': [0, 1]}}

b = {0: {1: 'b'},
     1: [3, 4, 5],
     2: {22: 22, 33: 33},
     3: {'a': {2: 22, 3: 33}, 'b': [99, 88]}}
```

`merge(a, b)` produces,

```
{0: {0: 'a', 1: 'b'},
 1: [3, 4, 5],
 2: {22: 22, 33: 33},
 3: {'a': {1: 1, 2: 22, 3: 33}, 'b': [99, 88]}}
```

**EDIT: Python 2.6 version**

```
def merge(a, b):
    if isinstance(b, dict) and isinstance(a, dict):
        a_and_b = set(a).intersection(b)
        every_key = set(a).union(b)
        return dict((k, merge(a[k], b[k]) if k in a_and_b else
                     deepcopy(a[k] if k in a else b[k])) for k in every_key)
    return deepcopy(b)
```

Comment: Errr, quick question:

I'm getting a syntax error when trying this in Python 2.6.2. I forgot to mention I need to run this in both 2.6.2 and 2.7.3. 

I'm guessing there's something in this code that got added after 2.6.2?

Comment: Right, so the first "return" statement uses dictionary comprehension? I can probably break that into a loop instead, and it should work fine in 2.6.2. Less elegant, but hey.

Comment: @SimonLundberg You can break the dict comprehension into a loop or you can also just call `dict` function on a generator expression of the key, value tuple. For 2.6 you're going to also have a problem with `viewkeys` method of the dictionaries. See my edit for a 2.6 solution.

Comment: Oh, so when you call dict on a generator (or, presumably, an existing iterable?), it produces a dictionary? I'd missed that. Good to know. 

Ah, thanks about the heads-up about viewkeys. It turns out it wasn't a problem, because the merging function actually only gets called in the 2.7.3 environment. Basically I've had to implement a few alternative code paths for different versions of the host software, as they have some difference. The old version is running 2.6.2 and the new one is 2.7.3. 

I'll switch from my loop version to the dict-generator combo instead just in case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. as long as you're not arbitrarily-nested, you don't need recursion.

```
from itertools import chain

{k:(v if not isinstance(v,dict) else dict(chain(a[k].items(), v.items()))) for k,v in b.items()}
Out[10]: {0: {0: 'a', 1: 'b'}, 1: [3, 4, 5]}
```

(I'm using python 3 here, feel free to replace `.items` with `.iteritems` in python 2)

Since this is a bit verbose, there's always the sneaky way to merge two dicts:

```
{k:(v if not isinstance(v,dict) else dict(a[k], **v)) for k,v in b.items()}
Out[11]: {0: {0: 'a', 1: 'b'}, 1: [3, 4, 5]}
```

You may or may not want to use this syntax - though it is compact, it kind of abuses cPython implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Needed something similar and implemented a more straightforward recursive solution. In-place updates dict 'd'.

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

def merge(d, v):
    """
    Merge two dictionaries.
    
    Merge dict-like `v` into dict-like `d`. In case keys between them are the same, merge
    their sub-dictionaries where possible. Otherwise, values in `v` overwrite `d`.
    """
    for key in v:
        if key in d and isinstance(d[key], MutableMapping) and isinstance(v[key], MutableMapping):
            d[key] = merge(d[key], v[key])
        else:
            d[key] = v[key]
    return d
```

Example 1:

```
a = {0: {0: "a"},
     1: [0, 1, 2]}

b = {0: {1: "b"},
     1: [3, 4, 5]}
     
>>> merge(a, b)
{0: {0: 'a', 1: 'b'}, 1: [3, 4, 5]}
```

Example 2:

```
a = {0: {0: 'a'},
     1: [0, 1, 2],
     2: [9, 9],
     3: {'a': {1: 1, 2: 2}, 'b': [0, 1]}}

b = {0: {1: 'b'},
     1: [3, 4, 5],
     2: {22: 22, 33: 33},
     3: {'a': {2: 22, 3: 33}, 'b': [99, 88]}}
     
>>> merge(a, b) 
{0: {0: 'a', 1: 'b'},
 1: [3, 4, 5],
 2: {22: 22, 33: 33},
 3: {'a': {1: 1, 2: 22, 3: 33}, 'b': [99, 88]}}
```