# Combine two hierarchy dictionaries (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, hierarchy

I have two hierarchy dictionaries that I need to combine into one. Dictionaries a & b only share a common root node (e.g. the CEO of the organisation), otherwise there is no overlap between them (e.g. a and b below are two separate lines of the business).

```
a = {'parent': '', 'name': 'CEO', 'children': [{'parent': 'CEO', 'name': 'Dir1'}]}
b = {'parent': '', 'name': 'CEO', 'children': [{'parent': 'CEO', 'name': 'Dir2'}]}
```

This is what the combined dictionary needs to look like, but how?

```
{'parent': '', 'name': 'CEO', 'children': [{'parent': 'CEO', 'name': 'Dir1'},{'parent': 'CEO', 'name': 'Dir2'}]}
```

I have tried

```
def Merge(dict1, dict2): 
    return(dict2.update(dict1)) 

def Merge(dict1, dict2): 
    res = {**dict1, **dict2} 
    return res
```

...but neither work for this due to the hierarchy nature of the dictionaries I assume.  I also tried this, but no success: [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693513/merging-hierarchy-of-dictionaries-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code should return what you need:

```
a = {'parent': '', 'name': 'CEO', 'children': [{'parent': 'CEO', 'name': 'Dir1'}]}
b = {'parent': '', 'name': 'CEO', 'children': [{'parent': 'CEO', 'name': 'Dir2'}]}

def Merge(dictionaries):
  children = []
  for d in dictionaries:
    children = children + d['children']
  return children

children = Merge([a,b])

new_dictionary = {'parent': '', 'name': 'CEO', 'chilren': children}

print(new_dictionary)
```

which will give you this:

```
{'parent': '', 'name': 'CEO', 'chilren': [{'parent': 'CEO', 'name': 'Dir1'}, {'parent': 'CEO', 'name': 'Dir2'}]}
```